# php cross files include paths confusion

Tags: php, include, document-root, dirname

Two files from different directory levels are simultaneously calling the same file:

```
// index.php
include('./include/same_file.php');

// Webpages/page1.php
include('../include/same_file.php');

// include/same_file.php
include('../template/header.php'); // failed to open on index.php
fopen('../files/text1.txt');       // failed to open on index.php
file('./files/AA.html');           // failed to open on /include/same_file.php
```

I have tried hours searching for solution and found the `dirname(__FILE__)` and `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` solutions but none of them works because none of them are giving detailed teaching to a beginner like me.

Comment: what is the detail of  dirname(__FILE__) u using?

Comment: So far I am only being told to do so: include(dirname(_FILE_).'../template/header.php'); but not working. I know something is missing but I don't know what!

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
require_once(__DIR__."/include/same_file.php");
```

or

```
include(__DIR__."/include/same_file.php");
```